# CSS tester for contrast and responsiveness

Tags: web-apps, css

I'm looking for something online that can effectively and properly test CSS code.

I tried [PowerMapper](http://www.powermapper.com/), and some of their results seem to be outdated. I tried [CheckMyColours](http://www.checkmycolours.com/) and they are happy with results. I even tried [Juicy Studio](http://juicystudio.com/services.php) and results are inconsistent from all three tools.

What I want to test primarily is contrast then responsiveness.

Does anyone know of a tool I can use?

Answer (score 3):

I use [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/pen/) for all my front end testing. It's probably the best site I've ever used for jquery/css/html testing. For CSS it includes SASS, SCSS, LESS, and Stylus with all their respected addons. I couldn't recommend it more for front end developers.